# Transform: Rotate background-color

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm having problems with transform: rotate on one of my headers. I'm trying to make the entire top half of the page have slight slant, this includes the text and the background. When I rotate the div it creates white space instead of filling the rest of the content in with the background color. The effect I'm trying to achieve is having the area outlined in blue to be the same red color so it expands from the left side of the page to the right. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="row bottom-align">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h1>Second-Title</h1>
      <h1>Another Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right bottom-align-text">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-outline"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.header {

  background-color: $red-primary;
  color: $white;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-5deg);

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try using a negative `margin-left` on the header; and maybe increase the `padding-left` by the same amount.

Comment: It generates a scrollbar which is no good.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden;` to the element that is getting the scrollbar.

Comment: That still generates a scroll bar

Comment: You could also try `position: relative; left: -20px;`. instead of negative `margin-left`; that should avoid any issues with horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of what Kevin was suggesting in the comments:

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
  background-color: #900;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 100px;
  margin: 0 -100px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="row bottom-align">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h1>Second-Title</h1>
      <h1>Another Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right bottom-align-text">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-outline"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-outline"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your header is left-justified relative to the window, you can probably use relative positioning to move your header back to the left, thus filling in the whitespace with the header background color.

```
.header {
    background-color: $red-primary;
    color: $white;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-5deg);

    /* Add this */
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    padding: auto 20px;

}
```